# Dynamically Create a div Using jQuery AJAX in Joomla?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, joomla

I have a `div` element holding two fields; a textbox and a text editor. I also have a button that says "Add". I need that button, when clicked, to add a new row, ie, dynamically repeat the `div`. How can I create this using jQuery AJAX. Also I must delete the selected row on onclick?

```
js = jQuery;
js('#add').on('click',function(){
    var id = js(".row-fluid:last").attr('id');
    var appendDiv = js(js(".row-fluid:last")[0].outerHTML);
    appendDiv.attr('id', ++id).insertAfter(".row-fluid:last");
});

   js('#remove').on('click',function(){
       var id = js(".row-fluid:last").attr('id');
       if(id != 0)
           js('#'+id).remove();
       else
           alert('parent field cannot be deleted');
      });
```

I tried using this. This works for me. But the text editor so created is not editable. So I am trying to create using jQuery AJAX. But I don't know how to write it.

This is the working HTML which I used with the jQuery

```
<div>
    <a href="#" name="add_more" id="add">Add</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="#" name="remove" id="remove">Remove</a>
</div>
<div id="0" class="row-fluid">            
    <div class="span10 form-horizontal">
        <fieldset class="adminform">
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="control-label">Days</div>
                <div class="controls"><input type="text" name="days[]"/</div>                                           
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="control-label">Details</div>
                <div class="controls">
                    <?php
                        $editor =& JFactory::getEditor();
                        $params = array(
                            'smilies'=> '0' ,
                            'style'  => '1' ,  
                            'layer'  => '0' , 
                            'table'  => '0' ,
                            'clear_entities'=>'0'
                        );
                        echo $editor->display( 'details[]', '', '400', '400',   '20', '20', false, $params );
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>              
        </fieldset>
    </div>            
</div>
```

Comment: and where is the code that show genuine effort you spend on this problem ?

Comment: @aish please show us the code that you are working on so that we can be more helpfull.

Comment: can you also give html code as well, so we can give you working result.

Comment: @aish Please check this link [making ajax call from joomla](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/146/what-is-the-proper-way-to-make-an-ajax-call-in-component)

Comment: thank you for the link. I have created the view page and it loads the div I have created. How can I repeat the process of creating div on button click. Now it shows only once.

Comment: I got it right, It was my mistake... I used append to display the output, I was trying with html. Thank you all...